# How to make combobox editable in a tablecell in javafx?

Tags: javafx, combobox, tablecell

I have set a Combobox in a tablecell using ComboBoxTableCell and now i want this combobox editable so that a user can edit it accordingly. I have made the editable property of combobox true but got no success. Below is the code.

```
            ComboBoxTableCell combo = new ComboBoxTableCell();                
           tc_target.setCellFactory(combo.forTableColumn(new 
            DefaultStringConverter(), trans));
            tc_target.setOnEditCommit(new 
          EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<File, String>>() {

                @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<File, String>event) {
                //work to do
           }

            });
     combo.setEditable(true);
```

how can i make this combobox editable ? Glad for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

The `ComboBoxTableCell` (and other similar classes) is not too clear in its Javadoc. The requirement to use `ComboBoxTableCell` correctly is:

1. The `TableColumn` must be editable.
2. The `TableView` that it belongs to must also be editable.

If you need to make sure other columns are not editable, then explicitly call `TableColumn.setEditable(false)` on those columns.

As a side note, you do not need to write `setOnEditCommit()`, and I am not sure if it would break the `ComboBoxTableCell` when you do so.

Comment: Both the TableColumn and the TableView were made editable but still got no luck in making ComboBox editable. What else need to be done?

Comment: @Ziva Is `setOnEditCommit()` removed yet?

Comment: I need to perform some task on the handle event of setOnEditCommit(), removing it, will not allow me to do that. How would I achieve it then?

Comment: @Ziva By default, `ComboBoxTableCell` is responsible for displaying the cell value via a `Label`, and the cell value is taken from the item that the row is representing. The `Label` changes into a `ComboBox` when it goes into edit mode. When you select a new value from the `ComboBox`, and when the `TableCell` loses focus, it commits back to the "item" that it got its original value from. If you do not want this behavior, you need to write your own cell factory callback.

Comment: I am new to this and not getting how to do it. Could you please show me the code for the same?

Comment: i also want a solution for this problem kindly help

Answer (score 0):

you can make this combobox editable like this

```
tc_target.setCellFactory(param -> {
    ComboBoxTableCell<File, String> tc = new ComboBoxTableCell<>(new DefaultStringConverter(), trans);
    tc.setComboBoxEditable(true);
    return tc;
});

tc_target.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<File, String>>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<File, String> event) {
        // work to do
    
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).